# Toast notification's parameters with XML

Tags: xml, windows, powershell, toast

In PowerShell with the help of XML I am trying to build up a toast notification. I have gone through the Microsoft's documentation for toast schema, but did not find the answer (or I do not know where to look)

Is it possible to remove the words `Windows Powershell` or change it to anything else?
The `S` letter is zoomed in picture. Is it possible to somehow show the whole minified picture there? Picture's pixels are 83x15.

[Toast Notification image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doFPy.png)

My XML:

```
[xml]$Toast = @"
<toast scenario="$Scenario">
    <visual>
    <binding template="ToastGeneric">
        <image id="1" placement="appLogoOverride" src="$LogoImage"/>
        <text >$AttributionText</text>
        <text>$HeaderText</text>
        <group>
            <subgroup>
                <text hint-style="title" hint-wrap="true" >$TitleText</text>
            </subgroup>
        </group>
        <group>
            <subgroup>     
                <text hint-style="body" hint-wrap="true" >$BodyText1</text>
            </subgroup>
        </group>
        <group>
            <subgroup>     
                <text hint-style="body" hint-wrap="true" >$BodyText2</text>
            </subgroup>
        </group>
    </binding>
    </visual>
    <actions>
        <action activationType="system" arguments="dismiss" content="$DismissButtonContent"/>
    </actions>
</toast>
"@
```

Answer (score 0):

At least the image is easy to fix, just edit your logo to be square 83x83 pixels